# Couldn't call controller method from route - Node.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have an `AuthenticationController` which has the method `signupWithCredentials`. I have another controller called `TestController` that works correctly though.

While making a `route`, I am getting this error:

```
router.post('/user/signup',
AuthenticationController.signupWithCredentials)
```

These are my routes:

```
'use strict'

const { Router } = require('express')
const { TestController } = require('./../controllers/TestController')
const { AuthenticationController } = require('./../controllers/AuthenticationController')
const { AuthMiddleware } = require('./../middleware/AuthMiddleware')

const router = new Router()

router.get('/test', TestController.test)

router.post('/user/signup', AuthenticationController.signupWithCredentials)

module.exports = router
```

This is my Controller class

```
'use strict'
const uuid = require('uuid/v4')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const config = require('./../config')

const { promiseEjs } = require('./../utils/promiseEjs')
const { mailSender } = require('./../utils/mailSender')
const { errorHandler } = require('./../utils/errorHandler')
const { User } = require('./../schema/user')
const { authMiddleWare } = require('./../middleware/AuthMiddleware')

class AuthenticationController {
    /**
     * API 1.0 | POST
     * @example {
        *      firstName: String,
        *      lastName: String,
        *      email: String,
        *      password: String
        *       }
        * @param {*} req
        * @param {*} res
        */
    static async signupWithCredentials (req, res) {
        try {
            let email = req.body.email
            let user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
            if (user) {
                throw {
                    code: 400, message: 'User already exist'
                }
            }
            else {
                let emailVerificationToken = uuid()
                user = new User({
                    firstName: req.body.firstName,
                    lastName: req.body.lastName,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8),
                    emailVerificationToken: emailVerificationToken
                })
                await user.save()
                try {
                    let emailVerificationLink = `${config.SERVER_DEV_URL}/authentication/verify?token=${emailVerificationToken}&user=${user._id}`
                    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') { emailVerificationLink = `${config.SERVER_PRODUCTION_URL}/authentication/verify?token=${emailVerificationToken}&user=${user._id}` }
                    let html = await promiseEjs.renderFile('./emails/signup.ejs', { user: user, emailVerificationLink: emailVerificationLink })
                    await mailSender.sendMail(user.email, 'Welcome to HandyGems', html)
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
                let authToken = authMiddleWare.createJWT(user)
                await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user._id }, { $set: { authToken: authToken } })
                res.send({ authToken: authToken })
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            errorHandler.sendError(res, error)
        }
    }
}

const authenticationController = new AuthenticationController()
module.exports = { authenticationController }
```

Comment: since the `AuthenticationController` is the one causing the problem, can you put its code into the question?

Comment: @molamk its already there.

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export your class instead of making an object of it

```
class AuthenticationController {
    static async signupWithCredentials (req, res) {
        console.log('you are just calling static method')
    }
    withoutStaticMethod(req, res) {
        console.log('you are just calling non static method using object')
    }
}
module.exports = AuthenticationController
```

If you have static method please don't make object and call it direactly using class Name like below code in your routes file

```
const AuthenticationController  = require('./AuthenticationController')
router.get('/signup', AuthenticationController.signupWithCredentials)
```

if You want to call non static method like withoutStaticMethod then you must have to make object of class to get 
functionality of class

```
const obj  = new AuthenticationController()
router.get('/testing2', obj.withoutStaticMethod)
```

**Static method calls are made directly on the class and are not callable on instances of the class.** Static methods are often used to create utility functions.

You need to call them using the class name: `CLASSNAME.STATIC_METHOD_NAME()` or by calling the method as a property of the constructor: `this.constructor.STATIC_METHOD_NAME()`.